# Reference dictionary keys in ArcGIS Tool Validation

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, dictionary, tool-validation

I have a Python script that is stored in a custom toolbox in ArcGIS Pro. The script has a dictionary `myDict` that I want the keys of to appear as a drop-down list as an input for the tool.

I know how to create a list in the Tool Validation function of the tool properties (`self.params[0].filter.list = ["Key1", "Key2"]`), but can you dynamically reference a list/dictionary in the script that the tool runs?

Comment: Is the dictionary built in the validation code? If so `myDict.keys()` would return a list of key values that you could feed into the filter.

Comment: @Hornbydd the dictionary is defined in the main script, not in the ToolValidator class. I was hoping for a way to reference the dictionary in ToolValidator without having to duplicate it.

Comment: If the dictionary is always the same content may be you could define it as a global object? So create and populate it after the import statements, then it will be accessible to all the code.